# Query for records modified last 15 minutes

Tags: apex, soql, workflow, formula, query

How can I set up a query to search for records that were modified in the last 15 minutes? This is being used in Jitterbit dataloader not using apex. From most posts I have seen this doesn't seem possible.

Another idea I had was use a formula that would mark a boolean field as true if record was modified in last 15 minutes. However, I had no luck with the formula either.

Does anyone have a workaround or solution?

Comment: Couldn't you just make the formula *number of minutes*?

Comment: What didn't work with the formula field approach? It should work, although once you get too far beyond ~100k records the performance would slowly drop off, since you can't index a non-deterministic formula like this.

Comment: I use jitterbit for an operation that runs daily, and reads/writes to a custom setting to store/update the 'last run date/time' so that i can use that value in my query filter in jitterbit, to filter only records modified since my last run date, and to avoid the non-selective query on large object error that would happen when you get near 100k records as ca_peterson indicates above.  I dont see any reason you couldnt do that every 15 minutes.  Can post more info / complete answer if helpful.

Comment: Sorry just realized you are using the JB data loader and not their paid product, which is what we are using.  I don't think the data loader let's you do multi step operations.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to make the following `Minutes_Since_Modified__c` formula work:

```
(NOW() - LastModifiedDate) * 24 * 60
```

Then I was able to query for it:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Minutes_Since_Modified__c < 15
```

Comment: very useful for my integration work, less integration functions. Thanks.